# C# Regex replace some HTML sequences with <p>, some with </p>

Tags: c#, regex

C#, .NET environment.

In a HTML string I am trying to replace any occurrences of one or more new line characters (`\n`) that are preceded by a HTML tag but not followed by another HTML tag with a `<p>`, and any occurrence of one or more new line characters not preceded by a HTML tag but followed by a HTML tag with a `</p>`.

As an example:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>

Some text here

<h2>Subheading</h2>
```

...Would be updated to:

`<h1>Heading</h1><p>Some text here</p><h2>Subheading</h2>`

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
string result = "some HTML content";

string pattern = @">(\n+)[^<]";
result = Regex.Replace(result, pattern, "<p>", RegexOptions.Multiline);

pattern = @"[^>](\n+)<";
result = Regex.Replace(result, pattern, "</p>", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: [Here an idea at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JrMQYo/1), try if this meets your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: https://regex101.com/r/kMxvyV/1

Search: `>(\n+)([^<])`
Replace: `><p>$2`

And: https://regex101.com/r/bmjX2N/1

Search: `([^>])(\n+)<`
Replace: `$1</p><`

Some characters in your original replace action where missing. I tried to add them again to the replacement string.

Comment: Thank you, I should have thought of that! It works well, but I think there's one typo in your answer for the second Replace: it should be `Replace: $1</p><`.

Comment: Thanks, corrected that in the text, not in the link to regexp101.